# How to write technical requirements

Tags: project-management, requirements

What is the right way to write technical requirements for the UI component in an application? I guess it's not clear to me whether the technical requirement should dictate how the UI should be implemented or it should be as general as possible and describe what are required to satisfy the functional requirements and forget about the implementation details.

Here are my specific questions:

- Should it state what technology the UI will be implemented in? (eg, ActiveX, WPF, HTML).
- Should I describe the layout, the colors? (given that that can change)
- Is it necessary to describe how the data is presented? (eg, does it need to say "data is displayed in a table or list format" or "a scrollbar shall appear is data cannot be fit on the screen"?)
- Do I need to describe how the UI should react to user input if that is a functional requirement? (eg, the functional requirement says "it shall be clear to the user which action is current active"... should the technical requirement say "the button shall change color to Red when user selects option a.. Blue when user selects option b.. etc")
- Is it necessary to state things that are common sense about the UI? For example,"it shall be position in such a way the entire content is visible"? or "it shall have shadow so that it stands out from the rest of the screen"? (note: these are not functional requirements but they apply to any UI in general)

Comment: the first question is: who will be reading this?

Answer (score 2):

There are no concrete rules here. The true answer is that it depends on what your team is composed of.

- If the person writing the requirements is the technical lead, then it may well dictate the technology choice.
- If however the person writing the requirements is a non-technical manager, then it's generally in the best interest to let the technical team decide on specifics while the manager merely dictates specific requirements that must be implemented.
- Additionally, things like layout and colors probably don't have a place in technical requirements. Someone (whether it's the development team, or if available, a designer) should come up with mockups or wireframes to review with the users. This is an iterative process and can usually be done in parallel with some of the initial development (ie. developers can usually start writing domain models, database schemas, etc. while the designer iterates the UI with the users/stakeholders).
- IMO, obvious things should be left out as they are just clutter, however, business rules such as validation, and screen states should absolutely.

Again, I want to reitorate that it entirely depends on the makeup of the team. The requirements doc is meant to communicate from one tier to another. And all decisions should be left to the tier best equipped to make those decisions.